# Active Directory GPO for Password Policy Not Applying from Default Domain Policy

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy, password

Ok. I have implemented a Password Policy. I know from previous posts that it cannot be applied from within an OU so I have configured it from the Default Domain Policy. I run RSOP.msc from a client machine and the policy settings are displayed with the Source GPO "Default Domain Policy." So it appears that it is working, but it's not. For example, I have a complexity requirement, but it accepts the password "a." It also allows me to change my password within Windows Security while the setting is "Minimum password age" of 89 days. Clearly the policy is not actually being applied!

What to do?

```
RSOP results for XXXX\XXXX on XXXXX-XXXXX: Logging Mode
----------------------------------------------------------

OS Type:                     Microsoft Windows XP Professional
OS Configuration:            Member Workstation
OS Version:                  5.1.2600
Domain Name:                 XXXXXX
Domain Type:                 Windows 2000
Site Name:                   XXXXXX
Roaming Profile:
Local Profile:               C:\Documents and Settings\XXXXX
Connected over a slow link?: No


COMPUTER SETTINGS
------------------

    CN=XXXXXXXXX,OU=UserComputers,DC=corp,DC=XXXXX,DC=com
    Last time Group Policy was applied: 10/14/2011 at 3:58:40 PM
    Group Policy was applied from:      tfs.corp.emergingmed.com
    Group Policy slow link threshold:   0 kbps

    Applied Group Policy Objects
    -----------------------------
        Published Software
        Copy of Base
        Default Domain Policy

    The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
        Local Group Policy
            Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)

    The computer is a part of the following security groups:
    --------------------------------------------------------
        BUILTIN\Administrators
        Everyone
        SQLServerMSSQLServerADHelperUser$XXXXX
        BUILTIN\Users
        NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK
        NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
        XXXXXXX$
        Domain Computers
        People


USER SETTINGS
--------------
    CN=XXXXXX,OU=Employees,DC=corp,DC=XXXX,DC=com
    Last time Group Policy was applied: 10/14/2011 at 3:58:40 PM
    Group Policy was applied from:      tfs.corp.XXXXX.com
    Group Policy slow link threshold:   0 kbps

    Applied Group Policy Objects
    -----------------------------
        Published Software
        Startup Scripts
        Copy of Base
        Default Domain Policy

    The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
        Local Group Policy
            Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)

    The user is a part of the following security groups:
    ----------------------------------------------------
        Domain Users
        Everyone
        BUILTIN\Administrators
        Remote Desktop Users
        BUILTIN\Users
        NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
        NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
        LOCAL
```

Comment: Just to rule out weirdness, have you done a `gpupdate` on an affected machine?

Comment: I restarted the machine several times since it was computer policy and my understanding is that computer policy changes require a restart - and upon restart it should do a gprefresh. I just did one anyway though and I posted the gpresult above.

Comment: Do you think it matters that my PC is in an OU (UserComputers)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The password policy should be applied to the OU of the servers where the account database is.  If you are trying to control the password on the active directory this means your policy should be applied to Domain Controllers OU.  If you have inheritance blocked on your Domain Controllers OU, then modifying the Default Domain policy which is linked at the root by default will not do what you want.

By setting the policy at the default domain level you are probably controlling the password policy of your workstation.  By this I mean the local accounts on your workstations would have now have the password requirements. Try creating a local account and setting a password.

This is partly relates to the same reason why you cannot have more then one password policy in a pre Windows 2008 domain.  The policy must be applied to all the Domain Controllers, so there is no way to distinguish between different users/computers.

Even with the [fine-grained policies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770394%28WS.10%29.aspx) in 2008 you cannot simply use a group policy, you have to setup special attributes in LDAP to have different objects target different password policies.

Comment: You sir are excellent